# pre-commit/pylint : two types possible for my input, but it doesn't get that in the instructions

Tags: python, union, typing

This is the code I have so far, but my input can be a boolean or a list of size 2 (str and int). Here is part of the code :

```
        # In the function arguments
        structured: Union[List[bool], bool]
        grid: Union[List[bool], bool]
        
        # instructions
        if structured is False or grid is False:
            self.structured: bool = False
        else:
            self.structured = True
            self.eltType = structured[0]
            self.Lx = grid[0]
            self.Ly = grid[1]
            self.Lz = structured[1]
```

But I get the error :

```
error: Value of type "Union[List[bool], Literal[True]]" is not indexable  [index]
```

The thing is that the first if statement tackles the case when grid/structured are bool and the else when they are arrays.

My second question is how to annotate an array that contains a str and an int.

```
List[Union[str,int]]  # maybe ?
```

Comment: `Union[List[bool], bool]` seems like an unusual type for a variable to me. I prefer to keep my types as simple as possible. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Side note. Instead of a comment `# In the function arguments`, you should write the actual `def` line in your question.

Comment: Do you ever change the elements of that list? It seems that a tuple is a better fit for the type of your entity otherwise.

Comment: One question per post, but if you are going to use static typing, think hard about why you would want a non-homogeneous list in the first place.

Comment: Also for tuple you could hint `Typle[str, bool]` like this. And slightly offtop: use sneak case when writing python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition, if false, doesn't guarantee for type-narrowing purposes that either variable is a list, only that at least one of them equals `False`.

Use a more explicit condition:

```
self.structured: bool
if isinstance(structured, list) and isinstance(structured, list):
     self.structured = True
     self.eltType = structured[0]
     self.Lx = grid[0]
     self.Ly = grid[1]
     self.Lz = structured[1]
else:
    self.structured = False
```

Since a value of `True` doesn't seem to make sense for either variable, consider a more constrained type like `Optional[list[bool]]` instead. Then you *only* have either `None` or a (not necessarily long enough) list.

```
# In the function arguments
structured: Optional[List[bool]]
grid: Optional[List[bool]]
    
self.structured: bool
if structured is not None and grid is not None:
    # Both must be lists
    self.structured = True
    self.eltType = structured[0]
    self.Lx = grid[0]
    self.Ly = grid[1]
    self.Lz = structured[1]
else:
    # One of them might be a list, but we'll ignore it.
    self.structured: bool = False
```